# Need a css or jquery solution to expand a nested div to 100%

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nested relative positioned div needs to have a 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619298/nested-relative-positioned-div-needs-to-have-a-100-height)

I haven't figured out what needs to be done to get this http://osf.fivetoolsoftware.com white nested div to expand to 100% height of the container size.  I have tried css variations for a few hours and have nothing to show for it.

Original question: [nested relative positioned div needs to have a 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619298/nested-relative-positioned-div-needs-to-have-a-100-height)

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it in your javascript file or in a javascript block (make sure you've included jquery above this code)

```
var h = window.innerHeight;         
$('div#canvas').css({'height':h+'px'});
```

Comment: You'll also then want to delete the div ID push and changes your footer image to be a transparent image without the grey part

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619298/nested-relative-positioned-div-needs-to-have-a-100-height

Comment: selected as an answer cause your solution was close.  I'm still hoping for a css solution to this issue though...

Comment: Yes, I tried a few css techniques but they didn't work. I figured you wouldn't mind jquery since you tagged the question with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could try this:

```
  <style>
  .expand{
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
  }
  .block{
     display:block;
  }
  </style>
```

And your html would be:

```
  <div class="block" ...> <!-- Parent div -->
    <div class="expand" ...> Your div </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: width?  display block on set a 100% width?